# How close in space do photons have to be for the Hong-Ou-Mandel effect to occur?

Tags: optics, quantum-optics

I've been reading about the [Hong-Ou-Mandel effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong%E2%80%93Ou%E2%80%93Mandel_effect), and I'm a little curious about how the apparatus is set up.  At the beam splitter, how close in space do the photons need to be for the effect to occur?

If it helps to answer the question, consider two circular laser beams of radius r, which during the actual experiment will be attenuated to single photon levels. How does the extent of the two-photon interference change as the beam overlap increases/decreases?

[image: HOM diagram]

(A diagram of full/no overlap, to clarify what I mean by "beam overlap")

Comment: Not a beam splitter ... you mean beam combiner!  ?  The beams must overlap in phase/time .... at least that is mostly how the effect is observed.

Answer (score 1):

The HOM effect is only shown when using pulsed photons. The experiment shows that the coincidence count goes below the flat portion when the pulses overlap in time. The same is true about their spatial overlap. My theoretical calculation suggests the overlap is proportional to
$\int_{space,time} |\Phi_1 \Phi_2|^2$.

The reason behind the HOM effect can be viewed in two ways. First, the dip in coincidence count occurs when two classical pulsed waves overlap. However, the dip goes only to 50% of the flat level. When reducing the power of the light sources to single photon level, both the flat level and the dip are reduced one notch with the dip becoming 0 because the coincidence count from a pulse being partially transmitted and reflected at the same time disappears.

The second view is around the boson nature of photons: the more the two photons overlap, the more they are indistinguishable. When they are indistinguishable, the outcome of the two photons exiting in two separate ways is the same as each photon being both transmitted and reflected by the beamsplitter. Of course, this outcome cannot occur.

By the way, indistinguishability should also be reflected in the frequency and spectral properties for the HOM effect to occur.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quantum mechanics for this. Just treat it as normal light, i.e., how to set it up so you can see interference.

If your beams do not overlap, you will not see any interference, be it quantum or not.